# Blender (2.93.1) - surface flicker - totally stuck

Tags: mesh, materials, camera, transforms, lighting

I am working on a Blender project (2.93.1) and when my camera moves, I get flickering surfaces all over my ISS space station. I'm usually rendering my sequences as dpx files and then work on them in DaVinci Resolve.

I have checked with the face orientation view option and there seems to be some conflict, but my Blender skill isn't sufficient to identify and solve the issue. When going into edit mode there seems to be no overlap of faces, the panels are thin but it seems that faces are clean and separated. I tried all kinds of fixes, like appending the entire scene into a new project or de-activating the auto-smooth function. Could not find a solution.

[Blend the file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/san0ydetb9lknmw/AABrAy6xQFnSztYuciPyycjZa?dl=0)

Comment: are you sure you don't have overlapping faces?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos - noted, will prepare the question in a better way next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see any surface flicker and I rendered one frame using your file perfectly fine with no issues, so from my experience I can think of 2 possible scenarios here:

1. There is something wrong with your GPU drivers and it glitches while rendering. In this case update the drivers or try CPU rendering. I don't think this is a very likely scenario.
2. You are actually observing the noise in the images that is caused by not enough samples set in the render settings. You could use denoising to clean this noise, but it may also flicker a bit, if there is still not enough samples, so you might need to increase the amount of samples even if you are using denoising. You may also just increase the amount of samples until the image has no more noise without using denoising. This will increase render time even more, but will give you most precise result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advise Martynas. Indeed cranking up the render samples to 512 or even 1024 has fixed the issue. My original render samples setting was at 128. I'm not quite clear why - I have done numerous animations with different models on 128 or 256 and while there was noise, I didn't see the effect that entire segments were flickering. Thanks again for the guidance, much appreciated!

Comment: Every scene with different lighting scenario is a bit different so rendering might require different settings as well. I, for example, can only dream about rendering my interior visualisations clean with only 1000 samples. Without denoising it might take 15 000 samples for the render to clear up fully.  I used to render like that on sheepit render farm before AI denoising. You mostly have direct lighting, so 1000 works well in this case.